# Delete row from React table with express and axios

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a backend server running on localhost:3001 concurrently with frontend on localhost:3000 . I have created a table in React and populated it with data from the backend endpoint localhost:3001/food.

Now I'm trying to implement functionality for the delete buttons in my table which should delete the row on the frontend and row in the database based on the id. When the delete button is clicked, it opens a modal which has a confirm delete button. Once that is clicked, the id of the row is passed to a function.

I'm not sure how to call the express function in the backend that does the deletion query to the database now. Do I do this directly in my index.js file or work in the axios one? I'm very new with React so I'd appreciate some help with this!

This is my table in index.js file (I omitted some unnecessary code for it):

```
const DataTable = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {mapCriterias.map(item => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{ item.id }</td>
                <td>{ item.food }</td>
                <td>{ renderDeleteButton(item.id) }</td>
              </tr>
            )
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}
```

My renderDeleteButton (also in index.js):

```
const renderDeleteButton = (key) => {
  let dialogEl=null;

  const delete_question = () => {
    // this is where my implementation would go
  }

  return (
    <>
      // modal
      <dialog ref={(el) => {
        dialogEl = el;
      }}>

        <div role="document">
          <h2>Are you sure you would like to delete this food?</h2>
          <p>This action cannot be undone</p>
          <form method="dialog">
            <div>
              <div>
                <button type="reset" onClick={()=>dialogEl.close()}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="del" id="delete_bottom" onClick {()=>delete_question()}>Delete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </dialog> 

      // delete button
      <button onClick={() =>dialogEl.showModal()} className="delete-btn">
        <span role="img">
          <Icon icon="gg:trash-empty"/>
        </span>
      </button>
    </>
  )
```

My fetch_db.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../credentials');

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM Food', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).send('Error')
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(results.rows)
    }
  })
});

router.delete('/:foodid', (req, res) => {
  pool.query('DELETE FROM Food WHERE foodid=$1', [req.params.foodid], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send('Error')
  } else {
    res.status(200).send('Success')
  }
});
```

My axios file that I use to fetch data from the db to populate my table:

```
import axios from "axios"

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3001"

export const getFoodData = () => {
  console.log("retrieved data");
  return axios.get("/food");
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server after making changes?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted my server

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question by removing all the detail. If you have a new question, ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Because your *delete* route is set up with this...

> ```js
> router.delete('/:foodid', ...
> ```

You need to send a `DELETE` request to `/food/<id>` then once that resolves successfully, remove the item from `mapCriterias` and close the modal.

For example

```js
// note the `async`
const delete_question = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/food/${encodeURIComponent(key)}`);
    // now remove the item from your state array
    // assuming you're using `useState`
    setMapCriterias((prev) => prev.filter(({ id }) => id !== key));

    dialogEl?.close(); // close the modal
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("delete_question", err.toJSON());
    // now show an error to the user or something ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }
};
```

---

On the server side, make sure that you're exporting the `router` from `fetch_db.js`...

```js
// at the end of fetch_db.js
module.exports = router;
```

In `server.js`, you appear to be using a lot of outdated methods and I can't see anywhere where you've registered your router.

Really, all you need is this

```js
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const foodRouter = require("./fetch_db"); // tweak the path if necessary

const port = 3001;

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Register global middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://your-prod-domain"],
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.use(express.json());

// Register routes
app.use("/food", foodRouter);

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I have tried this out and my second error goes away. However now I get `DELETE http://localhost:3001/foodid/1 404 (Not Found)` and `delete_question {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', description: undefined, number: undefined, fileName: undefined, …}`

Comment: @viktor you've gone and changed the URL again. It's `/food/...`, **not** `/foodid/...`

Comment: I have updated my code in the question. I think it's actually supposed to be just `http://localhost:3001/${encodeURIComponent(key)}` according to the format in fetch_db.js

Comment: No, it's not. Why are you using anything other than what's in my answer? You've prefixed your _food_ routes with `/food` via `app.use("/food", foodRouter)`

Comment: Oh ok, I thought I just got it wrong. But ya I tried what you showed in your answer and it is still showing those errors.

Comment: What errors **exactly**?

Comment: Omg, turns out it was one of the urls. The errors are gone now, but when I delete it, it still shows in the database

Comment: Well, you are deleting from the `Criteria` table and not `Food` so that's not particularly surprising

Comment: I had the original table name written in the question by mistake. I updated it to Food now. It's consistent on my end though

Comment: What does your debugging show? What is the value of `results` in the query callback? What DB library are you using? Are you sure you've got a `foodid` column? Your React app seems to be using `id` instead

Comment: My results show a success message: `{data: 'Success', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`. I am using postgres (pgAdmin). And yup `foodid` is a column in my database. I want to delete where foodid=id from the Food table.

Comment: No, not the HTTP response, the one in your `DELETE` query... `(error, results) => { ... }`. What specific JavaScript library are you using to execute queries? Where does `pool` come from? Is it [pg / node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)?

Comment: Ok I think it's working. It was deleting from a previous database I had included in my credentials for some reason. Thank you so much for all your help Phil!! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onClick={() => delete_question((prevValue) => !prevValue)}` in your button. You also need to make some changes in the file or query where you defined the `delete_question` param.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. How is this calling the delete request in the express file? What is prevValue supposed to represent? Please provide a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are keeping your axios routes separate, just add another route similar to the GET, just with either a POST or DELETE request, like so:

```
export const deleteFoodItem = (id) => {
  console.log("deleting data");
  return axios.post(`/food:${id}`);
}
```

And then in your `renderDeleteButton` component, import it and use it like:

```
import {deleteFoodItem} from "../axiosfilepath";

<button onClick={()=> deleteFoodItem(id)}>Delete button</button>
```

**Just a couple notes about React:**

You should name your components with PascalCase.

You don't need to use fragments (<></>) unless you don't wrap all elements in some container/wrapper.

(Might be preferential, but I find it simpler than using refs) You can keep modals really simple by toggling the modal with a `const [modalOpen, setModal] = useState(false)` and then inside the modal component setting display: none when false.

Comment: I tried this method using delete instead of post, but I get an error saying `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/foodid:1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` I also get `Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

Comment: CORS is kind of like a safety precaution so that malicious code won't be run from origins that aren't expected. If you google Express and CORS you can find more info, but essentially you need to install and setup cors middleware like so: `const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://www.section.io'
}));` on your Express server

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just was showing an example hoping to point him in the right direction. For his current usecase, replacing the above url with `https://localhost:3000` would be appropriate of course, but only for local development.

Comment: Fair enough. Just for OP or anyone else's reference setting the cors middleware to default (`app.use(cors())`) opens your server up to ALL requests, as stated [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) in the docs near the top. So remember to set it more deliberately before opening your server up to the internet

Comment: CORS is not access control. Your app would be _open_ to anything no matter what your CORS configuration was

Comment: That is true, of course. Apologies if my replies seemed overly simplistic or to be stating that handling CORS would solve all access control/security concerns. OP was asking about his CORS policy error, so hopefully he has enough info now to fix that error and move forward with his project.